# How to convert json data that has date as attribute to dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I used a converter but the result was wrong...
Am trying to develop application about Covid-19 using flutter and am kinda stuck on this format of result.I need to converted to dart to keep working on the app so any help will be appreciate and thanks in advance :)

#### This is the result of the request from the api:

```
[  
  {  
    "country": "Afghanistan",  
    "province": null,  
    "timeline": {  
      "cases": {  
        "3/16/20": 21,  
        "3/17/20": 22,  
        "3/18/20": 22,  
        "3/19/20": 22,  
        "3/20/20": 24,  
        "3/21/20": 24,  
        "3/22/20": 40,  
        "3/23/20": 40,  
        "3/24/20": 74,  
        "3/25/20": 84,  
        "3/26/20": 94,  
        "3/27/20": 110,  
        "3/28/20": 110,  
        "3/29/20": 120,  
        "3/30/20": 170,  
        "3/31/20": 174,  
        "4/1/20": 237,  
        "4/2/20": 273,  
        "4/3/20": 281,  
        "4/4/20": 299,  
        "4/5/20": 349,  
        "4/6/20": 367,  
        "4/7/20": 423,  
        "4/8/20": 444,  
        "4/9/20": 484,  
        "4/10/20": 521,  
        "4/11/20": 555,  
        "4/12/20": 607,  
        "4/13/20": 665,  
        "4/14/20": 714  
      },  
      "deaths": {  
        "3/16/20": 0,  
        "3/17/20": 0,  
        "3/18/20": 0,  
        "3/19/20": 0,  
        "3/20/20": 0,  
        "3/21/20": 0,  
        "3/22/20": 1,  
        "3/23/20": 1,  
        "3/24/20": 1,  
        "3/25/20": 2,  
        "3/26/20": 4,  
        "3/27/20": 4,  
        "3/28/20": 4,  
        "3/29/20": 4,  
        "3/30/20": 4,  
        "3/31/20": 4,  
        "4/1/20": 4,  
        "4/2/20": 6,  
        "4/3/20": 6,  
        "4/4/20": 7,  
        "4/5/20": 7,  
        "4/6/20": 11,  
        "4/7/20": 14,  
        "4/8/20": 14,  
        "4/9/20": 15,  
        "4/10/20": 15,  
        "4/11/20": 18,  
        "4/12/20": 18,  
        "4/13/20": 21,  
        "4/14/20": 23  
      },  
      "recovered": {  
        "3/16/20": 1,  
        "3/17/20": 1,  
        "3/18/20": 1,  
        "3/19/20": 1,  
        "3/20/20": 1,  
        "3/21/20": 1,  
        "3/22/20": 1,  
        "3/23/20": 1,  
        "3/24/20": 1,  
        "3/25/20": 2,  
        "3/26/20": 2,  
        "3/27/20": 2,  
        "3/28/20": 2,  
        "3/29/20": 2,  
        "3/30/20": 2,  
        "3/31/20": 5,  
        "4/1/20": 5,  
        "4/2/20": 10,  
        "4/3/20": 10,  
        "4/4/20": 10,  
        "4/5/20": 15,  
        "4/6/20": 18,  
        "4/7/20": 18,  
        "4/8/20": 29,  
        "4/9/20": 32,  
        "4/10/20": 32,  
        "4/11/20": 32,  
        "4/12/20": 32,  
        "4/13/20": 32,  
        "4/14/20": 40  
      }  
    }  
  },  
...  
]
```

#### And this the result from converter:

```
class Historic {
  String country;
  Null province;
  Timeline timeline;

  Historic({this.country, this.province, this.timeline});

  Historic.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    country = json['country'];
    province = json['province'];
    timeline = json['timeline'] != null
        ? new Timeline.fromJson(json['timeline'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['country'] = this.country;
    data['province'] = this.province;
    if (this.timeline != null) {
      data['timeline'] = this.timeline.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Timeline {
  Cases cases;
  Cases deaths;
  Cases recovered;

  Timeline({this.cases, this.deaths, this.recovered});

  Timeline.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    cases = json['cases'] != null ? new Cases.fromJson(json['cases']) : null;
    deaths = json['deaths'] != null ? new Cases.fromJson(json['deaths']) : null;
    recovered = json['recovered'] != null
        ? new Cases.fromJson(json['recovered'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.cases != null) {
      data['cases'] = this.cases.toJson();
    }
    if (this.deaths != null) {
      data['deaths'] = this.deaths.toJson();
    }
    if (this.recovered != null) {
      data['recovered'] = this.recovered.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Cases {
  int i31620;
  int i31720;
  int i31820;
  int i31920;
  int i32020;
  int i32120;
  int i32220;
  int i32320;
  int i32420;
  int i32520;
  int i32620;
  int i32720;
  int i32820;
  int i32920;
  int i33020;
  int i33120;
  int i4120;
  int i4220;
  int i4320;
  int i4420;
  int i4520;
  int i4620;
  int i4720;
  int i4820;
  int i4920;
  int i41020;
  int i41120;
  int i41220;
  int i41320;
  int i41420;

  Cases(
      {this.i31620,
      this.i31720,
      this.i31820,
      this.i31920,
      this.i32020,
      this.i32120,
      this.i32220,
      this.i32320,
      this.i32420,
      this.i32520,
      this.i32620,
      this.i32720,
      this.i32820,
      this.i32920,
      this.i33020,
      this.i33120,
      this.i4120,
      this.i4220,
      this.i4320,
      this.i4420,
      this.i4520,
      this.i4620,
      this.i4720,
      this.i4820,
      this.i4920,
      this.i41020,
      this.i41120,
      this.i41220,
      this.i41320,
      this.i41420});

  Cases.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    i31620 = json['3/16/20'];
    i31720 = json['3/17/20'];
    i31820 = json['3/18/20'];
    i31920 = json['3/19/20'];
    i32020 = json['3/20/20'];
    i32120 = json['3/21/20'];
    i32220 = json['3/22/20'];
    i32320 = json['3/23/20'];
    i32420 = json['3/24/20'];
    i32520 = json['3/25/20'];
    i32620 = json['3/26/20'];
    i32720 = json['3/27/20'];
    i32820 = json['3/28/20'];
    i32920 = json['3/29/20'];
    i33020 = json['3/30/20'];
    i33120 = json['3/31/20'];
    i4120 = json['4/1/20'];
    i4220 = json['4/2/20'];
    i4320 = json['4/3/20'];
    i4420 = json['4/4/20'];
    i4520 = json['4/5/20'];
    i4620 = json['4/6/20'];
    i4720 = json['4/7/20'];
    i4820 = json['4/8/20'];
    i4920 = json['4/9/20'];
    i41020 = json['4/10/20'];
    i41120 = json['4/11/20'];
    i41220 = json['4/12/20'];
    i41320 = json['4/13/20'];
    i41420 = json['4/14/20'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['3/16/20'] = this.i31620;
    data['3/17/20'] = this.i31720;
    data['3/18/20'] = this.i31820;
    data['3/19/20'] = this.i31920;
    data['3/20/20'] = this.i32020;
    data['3/21/20'] = this.i32120;
    data['3/22/20'] = this.i32220;
    data['3/23/20'] = this.i32320;
    data['3/24/20'] = this.i32420;
    data['3/25/20'] = this.i32520;
    data['3/26/20'] = this.i32620;
    data['3/27/20'] = this.i32720;
    data['3/28/20'] = this.i32820;
    data['3/29/20'] = this.i32920;
    data['3/30/20'] = this.i33020;
    data['3/31/20'] = this.i33120;
    data['4/1/20'] = this.i4120;
    data['4/2/20'] = this.i4220;
    data['4/3/20'] = this.i4320;
    data['4/4/20'] = this.i4420;
    data['4/5/20'] = this.i4520;
    data['4/6/20'] = this.i4620;
    data['4/7/20'] = this.i4720;
    data['4/8/20'] = this.i4820;
    data['4/9/20'] = this.i4920;
    data['4/10/20'] = this.i41020;
    data['4/11/20'] = this.i41120;
    data['4/12/20'] = this.i41220;
    data['4/13/20'] = this.i41320;
    data['4/14/20'] = this.i41420;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update i found solution:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Historic> historicFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Historic>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Historic.fromJson(x)));

String historicToJson(List<Historic> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Historic {
  String country;
  String province;
  Timeline timeline;

  Historic({
    this.country,
    this.province,
    this.timeline,
  });

  factory Historic.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Historic(
        country: json["country"],
        province: json["province"] == null ? null : json["province"],
        timeline: Timeline.fromJson(json["timeline"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "country": country,
        "province": province == null ? null : province,
        "timeline": timeline.toJson(),
      };
}

class Timeline {
  Map<String, int> cases;
  Map<String, int> deaths;
  Map<String, int> recovered;

  Timeline({
    this.cases,
    this.deaths,
    this.recovered,
  });

  factory Timeline.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Timeline(
        cases:
            Map.from(json["cases"]).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, int>(k, v)),
        deaths:
            Map.from(json["deaths"]).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, int>(k, v)),
        recovered: Map.from(json["recovered"])
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, int>(k, v)),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "cases": Map.from(cases).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v)),
        "deaths":
            Map.from(deaths).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v)),
        "recovered":
            Map.from(recovered).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v)),
      };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this simple function to turn the date strings to `DateTime` object.

```
DateTime parseDate(String raw){
    int year = int.parse(raw[2]);
    int month = int.parse(raw[0]);
    int day = int.parse(raw[1]);
    return DateTime(year, month, day);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An even faster way is to use [this web tool](https://app.quicktype.io/) for instant conversion from JSON. You just need to paste the JSON code in (remember to respect the format), choose the language output and voila!

Input (Copy this):

```json
{  
    "country": "Afghanistan",  
    "province": null,  
    "timeline": {  
      "cases": {  
        "3/16/20": 21,  
        "3/17/20": 22,  
        "3/18/20": 22,  
        "3/19/20": 22,  
        "3/20/20": 24,  
        "3/21/20": 24,  
        "3/22/20": 40,  
        "3/23/20": 40,  
        "3/24/20": 74,  
        "3/25/20": 84,  
        "3/26/20": 94,  
        "3/27/20": 110,  
        "3/28/20": 110,  
        "3/29/20": 120,  
        "3/30/20": 170,  
        "3/31/20": 174,  
        "4/1/20": 237,  
        "4/2/20": 273,  
        "4/3/20": 281,  
        "4/4/20": 299,  
        "4/5/20": 349,  
        "4/6/20": 367,  
        "4/7/20": 423,  
        "4/8/20": 444,  
        "4/9/20": 484,  
        "4/10/20": 521,  
        "4/11/20": 555,  
        "4/12/20": 607,  
        "4/13/20": 665,  
        "4/14/20": 714  
      },  
      "deaths": {  
        "3/16/20": 0,  
        "3/17/20": 0,  
        "3/18/20": 0,  
        "3/19/20": 0,  
        "3/20/20": 0,  
        "3/21/20": 0,  
        "3/22/20": 1,  
        "3/23/20": 1,  
        "3/24/20": 1,  
        "3/25/20": 2,  
        "3/26/20": 4,  
        "3/27/20": 4,  
        "3/28/20": 4,  
        "3/29/20": 4,  
        "3/30/20": 4,  
        "3/31/20": 4,  
        "4/1/20": 4,  
        "4/2/20": 6,  
        "4/3/20": 6,  
        "4/4/20": 7,  
        "4/5/20": 7,  
        "4/6/20": 11,  
        "4/7/20": 14,  
        "4/8/20": 14,  
        "4/9/20": 15,  
        "4/10/20": 15,  
        "4/11/20": 18,  
        "4/12/20": 18,  
        "4/13/20": 21,  
        "4/14/20": 23  
      },  
      "recovered": {  
        "3/16/20": 1,  
        "3/17/20": 1,  
        "3/18/20": 1,  
        "3/19/20": 1,  
        "3/20/20": 1,  
        "3/21/20": 1,  
        "3/22/20": 1,  
        "3/23/20": 1,  
        "3/24/20": 1,  
        "3/25/20": 2,  
        "3/26/20": 2,  
        "3/27/20": 2,  
        "3/28/20": 2,  
        "3/29/20": 2,  
        "3/30/20": 2,  
        "3/31/20": 5,  
        "4/1/20": 5,  
        "4/2/20": 10,  
        "4/3/20": 10,  
        "4/4/20": 10,  
        "4/5/20": 15,  
        "4/6/20": 18,  
        "4/7/20": 18,  
        "4/8/20": 29,  
        "4/9/20": 32,  
        "4/10/20": 32,  
        "4/11/20": 32,  
        "4/12/20": 32,  
        "4/13/20": 32,  
        "4/14/20": 40  
      }  
    }  
  }
```

Output:

```dart
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final historic = historicFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Historic historicFromJson(String str) => Historic.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String historicToJson(Historic data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Historic {
    Historic({
        this.country,
        this.province,
        this.timeline,
    });

    String country;
    dynamic province;
    Timeline timeline;

    factory Historic.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Historic(
        country: json["country"],
        province: json["province"],
        timeline: Timeline.fromJson(json["timeline"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "country": country,
        "province": province,
        "timeline": timeline.toJson(),
    };
}

class Timeline {
    Timeline({
        this.cases,
        this.deaths,
        this.recovered,
    });

    Map<String, int> cases;
    Map<String, int> deaths;
    Map<String, int> recovered;

    factory Timeline.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Timeline(
        cases: Map.from(json["cases"]).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, int>(k, v)),
        deaths: Map.from(json["deaths"]).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, int>(k, v)),
        recovered: Map.from(json["recovered"]).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, int>(k, v)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "cases": Map.from(cases).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v)),
        "deaths": Map.from(deaths).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v)),
        "recovered": Map.from(recovered).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v)),
    };
}
```